# How does the addition of two different length vectors work?

Tags: linear-algebra

This one for example:

$(1, −1, −3) + (7, 14)=?$

Should I take the second vector as $(7,14,0)$?

Comment: They can't be added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The very quick answer is:

It does **not work** simply because it is **not defined**.

Why is that: Usually you have a vector space $V$ which is a triplet $(V,+,\cdot)$, over some field $K$. Now take the $+$ (the canonical addition), which is binary operation over the vector space
$$
{+ \colon V\times V\to V}
$$
which means that you take two elements of $V$ and map them into $V$ once again. The bottom line is this, that you need elements of $V$ for this. In your case, these two elements come from different vector spaces and therefore the canonical addition is not defined.

Comment: ok thank you. Now I feel stupid.

Comment: @Lindow no need for this! why are you trying to add up these vectors this in the first place?

Comment: I was kidding. It was an exercise asking to do this actually. And it sepecify to do the addition when it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to add those two vectors as they live in different spaces. You could view $(7,14)$ as $(7,14,0)$, or as $(0,7,14)$ or as $(7,0,14)$ or in some other weird way. Since there is no unique way to view $(7,14)$ as a vector in 3 dimensions, you can not add them.